# C# [using] as data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, namespaces, data-annotations

I have an ambiguous reference between two methods from different classes.

This classes are in different namespaces that share the same structure like:

```
MyApp.Models.Folder1.Class1
MyApp.Models.Folder2.Class2
```

Why I can't use like this?

```
using MyApp.Models;
//and use this static method
Folder1.Class1.StaticMethod();
```

And is there any way to use a namespace just for a method? like:

```
[using(MyApp.Models.Folder1)]
public ContentResult SomeGetMethod(){
    if(Class1.StaticBooleanMethod()) return "nice baby!";
    return "that was horrible!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I can't use like this?

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx), a using directive does not give you access to any namespaces that are nested in the namespace you specify.

> And is there any way to use a namespace just for a method? like:

There is no way to do this, however you can fully qualify the name:

```
if (MyApp.Models.Folder1.Class1.StaticBooleanMethod()) return "nice baby!";
```

Or use an alias:

```
using Folder = MyApp.Models.Folder1;
...
if(Folder.Class1.StaticBooleanMethod()) return "nice baby!";
```